# Improving InsertAllOnSubmit Performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

I'm currently working on a small project to learn Linq where I want to create a large SDF database for a windows phone application on my desktop machine. The application I want to create takes a text files with tab delimited entries and should insert them into the SDF file. There are around 900000 lines in the file. Currently I'm inserting them this way:

```
                ConcurrentBag<Entry> data = new ConcurrentBag<Entry>();

                Parallel.ForEach<DictCCParser.Entry>(entries, e =>
                    {
                        Entry entry = new Entry { LanguageOne = e.Lang1, LanguageTwo = e.Lang2, GroupId = groupIds[e.Group] };
                        data.Add(entry);
                    });

                Console.WriteLine("Inserting data");

                db.Entries.InsertAllOnSubmit(data);
                db.SubmitChanges();
```

The problem is, that LINQ seems to create 900000 separate INSERT INTO statements. I've read that it is possible to use bulk insert, however every implementation I cam across needed a SQLCE 4.0 file. I tried to create a huge query containing all the Inserts like

```
             INSERT INTO Entries(LanguageOne, LanguageTwo, Group) VALUES (...),(...),(...)
```

But apparently SqlCE doesn't work with multiple inserts. Is there a way to speed up this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my SqlCeBulkCopy library, for Windows Phone the database MUST be 3.5 format - http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com

Comment: The database id created via DataContext.CreateDatabase(). I already tried using your library but it threw a sqlceinvaliddatabaseformatexception. Is there a way to check the format? Basically the DB is created similar to this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876(v=vs.92) but with a desktop application.